# Multiple AggFun in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If you think about pivot tables in `Excel`, you can add additional columns and change from sum to mean to min or max.  Is it possible to get the multiple values in a `pivot` in `Pandas`?

Here is a working example (lifted from the pandas documentation):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three'] * 6,
....:              'B' : ['A', 'B', 'C'] * 8,
....:              'C' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'] * 4,
....:              'D' : np.random.randn(24),
....:              'E' : np.random.randn(24),
....:              'F' : np.random.randn(24)})
```

Here is a pivot example:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values=['D', 'E'], rows=['B'], aggfunc=np.mean)
```

Which returns:

```
    D           E
B       
A   -0.083449   -0.242955
B    0.826492   -0.058596
C    0.124266   -0.197583
```

Is there a way I could take `np.sum` to the `pivot` example here?

Comment: Do you just want to use `np.sum` instead of `np.mean` or do you want both simultaneously?

Comment: Both simultaneously.  I could append the first pivot to add the second pivot data, but was wondering if it can be done in one swipe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a list to `pivot_table`'s `aggfunc` keyword argument:

```
>>> pd.pivot_table(df, values=['D', 'E'], rows=['B'], aggfunc=[np.mean, np.sum])
       mean                 sum          
          D         E         D         E
B                                        
A -0.102403  0.854174 -0.819224  6.833389
B  0.426928 -0.177344  3.415428 -1.418754
C -0.159123 -0.071418 -1.272980 -0.571341

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

(PS: you can also use the method version, i.e. `df.pivot_table(stuff)`.)