# pandas pivot_table multiple aggfunc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I create a pivot table on a dataframe I have, passing `aggfunc='mean'` works as expected, `aggfunc='count'` works as expected, however `aggfunc=['mean', 'count']` results in: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__`

This format seemed to work previously: [Multiple AggFun in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485139/multiple-aggfun-in-pandas)

How do I create a pivot table with multiple functions?

Comment: try passing in the functions themselves? e.g. `np.mean` as opposed to `'mean'`

Comment: When passing `aggfunc='np.mean'`, it works. If passing `aggfunc=['np.mean']`, it results in `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'np.mean'`

Comment: try this: `aggfunc=[np.mean]`. (notice no quotes)

Comment: That works. Now, how do I get the count of the values? I don't believe np.count exists

Comment: what about `pd.DataFrame.count`?

Comment: The dataframe is 6k rows long- I'm looking for the counts ~600 codes (rows in the pivot table), over the course of 15 months (cols). As of now, I'm sending a mean pivot table and a count pivot table to csv's, then combining in excel.

Comment: also, one last suggestion, try `len`?

Comment: That's it! `aggfunc=[np.mean, len]`

Comment: parenthesis ``('count','sum','mean')`` solution below actually works

Comment: to use np.mean you have to import numpy onto your script

Answer (score 16):

I've found that this works if you simply replace square brackets with ordinary brackets i.e.

```
aggfunc=('count','mean')
```

Answer (score 9):

An example:

```
In [59]: pivot_table(tips, rows=['sex', 'smoker'],
                     aggfunc={'tip_pct' : 'mean', 'size' : 'sum'})
Out[59]:
               size  tip_pct
sex    smoker
Female No      140   0.1569
       Yes     74    0.1822
Male   No      263   0.1607
       Yes     150   0.1528
```

Source: http://wesmckinney.com/blog/fast-and-easy-pivot-tables-in-pandas-0-5-0/

Comment: you are pointing to ancient pandas version ``0.5.0``, current version is ``0.19.0`` - this syntax is outdated